# Как представить, генерировать и хранить workflow в виде графа, для его последующего использования celery

Tags: python, celery, graph, workflow

Как workflow с последовательностями задач и групповыми задачами (представленный в виде графа) хранить в бд(postgresql или другой), и запускать когда происходит какое-либо событие (слушается Kafka).
Столкнулся с проблемой не понимания как организовать хранение, чтобы после получения workflow с задачами из бд можно было это преобразовать в workflow для celery, используя chain, group и тд. Схема примера workflow ниже
[image: рисунок]